# Reload a Backbone View After it Has Been Removed?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

After I remove a backbone view that views EL is also removed which is a bit of a problem for me.  The way my view is setup is that I have a PHP file that loads in

```
<div id="main_destinations" class="trip_container"></div>
```

and then that wrapper has a template loaded into it.  The problem I am having is that when I remove that view, I also am removing that wrapper and I'm not sure what I should do.  Is there a way to keep the wrapper? Should I be recreating this empty wrapper and then loading in the template into it.  What is the best way to handle this?

My understanding is that the EL needs to already be in the DOM before loading a view and attaching events so I don't understand why removing a view removes its EL.

UPDATE - HOW I REMOVE A VIEW:

```
if(typeof mysite.city != "undefined")
 {                      
  mysite.city.View.prototype.remove.call(cityViewValue);
 }
```

How I instantiate my view:

```
cityViewValue = new mysite.city.View(page, country, city, city_id);
```

Comment: Can you please post your code how are you removing your view? It is not necessary that your EL element should be present in DOM at the time of view creation. If you don't pass el, backbone is intelligent enough to create an empty div as el until you specify a tagname.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the definition of Backbone.View.Prototype.remove

```
function () {
  this.$el.remove();
  this.stopListening();
  return this;
}
```

It is clearly shown, it removes el element from DOM. Here is an alternative solution to your problem:
Create a refresh function in view, remove the element which you want to remove from your view and load the template in your view.

```
refresh: function() {
    this.$('.dynamic-data').remove(); //Assuming your element to be removed has class dynamic-data and is unique in this view. Otherwise we will write specific selector here
    var html = ; // Load template here
    $(this.el).append(html);
}
```